# I want to ignore all other tags except noun and verb tags. is it possible to do it using Stanford corenlp word class?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to ignore all other tags except noun and verb tags. is it possible to do it using Stanford corenlp word lavel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate POS tags using Stanford corenlp and then prune the ones not having verb and noun tags. Try [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process) to get a feel of how tagging is done for different input sentences and do read the POS tagging manual to get a hold of what different POS tag mean.